# show two different list as a matrix table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

I have two lists (item and obj) for which I will have input field that will look like this:

```
       item1           item2
obj1   input_field1   input_field2

obj2    input_field3  input_field4
```

Based on the input field data if filled up I will create obj1 record related to item1 record
How will I achieve this in aura?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show the community _what you've tried_ and _where you're stuck_. SFSE's format offers assistance with specific problems, but not complete implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.lists1}" var="list1">
            <tr>
                <td>{!list1.Name}</td>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lists2}" var="list2">
                    <td><input id="{!list2.Name+'-'+list1.Name}" value="{!list1.Name}"></input></td>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```